# Adding Acknowledgments to Settings bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am following this guide to add all the acknowledgments of my Pods into my app settings bundle.
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Acknowledgements

I am getting this:
[image]

I can see the acknowledgement.plist file and markdown into Xcode.
[image]

Suggestions?

Comment: Please post actual error messages instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you either do not have a Settings bundle or it does not have a Acknowledgements.plist file. If you look at the code for the post_install hook on the page you referenced, you see

```
FileUtils.cp_r('Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-Acknowledgements.plist', 'Resources/Settings.bundle/Acknowledgements.plist', :remove_destination => true)
```

You have verified that the Pods-Acklnowledgements.plist file exists. But if you look at your error message, the problem is with the copy destination, not the source.

I'm not sure if the `remove_destination => true` errors if the destination does not exist. So, first check to see that you have created a Settings bundle in your app. If you have, then I recommend adding a dummy Acknowledgements.plist file to it, so that the post-install hook has something to remove.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was with the path of my Settings.bundle. I just removed "Resources" and worked.